# scala deal with string and do accumulative

Tags: scala

I have variable:

```
val list= rows.sortBy(- _._2).map{case (user , list) => list}.take(20).mkString("::")
```

the result `println(list)` should be:

```
60::58::51::48::47::47::45::45::43::43::42::42::42::41::41::41::40::40::40::39
```

And now I have to deal with these numbers (like histogram concept)

If I set the break is 10, it should divide the max number (60) by 10 and make 6 buckets:

- the scope between   0~ 10`(0<x<=10)`    have 0 numbers match
- the scope between  10~ 20`(10<x<=20)`   have 0 numbers match
- the scope between  20~ 30`(20<x<=30)`   have 0 numbers match
- the scope between  30~ 40`(30<x<=40)`   have 4 numbers match
- the scope between  40~ 50`(40<x<=50)`   have 13 numbers match
- the scope between  50~ 60`(50<x<=60)`   have 3 numbers match

And then I have to save with 2 variables `x` and `y` :

```
x:  0~10::10~20::20~30::30~40::40~50::50~60
y:  0::0::0::4::13::3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val actualList = list.split("::").map(_.toInt).toList
val step = 10
val steps = step to actualList.max by step
//for each step, output a count of all items in the list that are 
//between the current step and currentStep - stepVal
val counts = steps.map(x=>actualList.count(y=>y <= x && y > x - step))
val stepsAsString = steps.map(x=>s"${x-step}~$x")
```

And you can map them too:

```
steps.zip(counts).toMap
```

Note that this could be made more performant if the list were sorted first, but I wouldn't worry about tuning unless you need it

Comment: Could you explain this line ````steps.map(x=>list.count(y=>y <= x && y > x - step))```` for me??    I get the result with some difference:````Map(10 -> 0, 20 -> 0, 50 -> 11, 40 -> 0, 30 -> 0)````  I think that I have to edit this line.

Comment: I found that if I did't add ````::Nil```` after ````39```` in the ````list````,I won't get the right answer(````Map(10 -> 0, 20 -> 0, 60 -> 3, 50 -> 13, 40 -> 4, 30 ->0)````). What I get is : ````Map(10 -> 0, 20 -> 0, 50 -> 11, 40 -> 0, 30 -> 0)````  But the string   is come from a variable called````list```` , so I can't add ````::Nil```` to it directly. Could you help me how to do??

Comment: fixed. You originally did not say that was a string. Although you really should just drop the mkString and use the list data directly

Comment: Thanks a lot.sitll not familiar with scala.I can move on now!

Comment: Justin Pilhony , I want to ask if I have to change x to ````x:  0~10::10~20::20~30::30~40::40~50::50~60```` How can I do?

Comment: I don't follow. You want it to be string instead of the key? Or a range, or what?

Comment: I want to save x from ````10::20::30::40::50::60```` to  ````0~10::10~20::20~30::30~40::40~50::50~60````. It would be much easy to understand for people see it.  It's string

Comment: Editted to add a map to do this.

Comment: Thank you a lot.Just one more question. Do you know ````ceil```` in php?   I met a problem. ````val steps = 10 to 62 by 10````  62 is not divisible by 10 so Ii have to produce 7 buckets in ````steps```` : ````Range(10,20,30,40,50,60,70)````    which method can I use?

Comment: There is a math.ceil, but I dont think that would fix the problem. You can use modulus to get to an even number : `(max - (max % step)) + step`